# Your answer may not make any sense to me

Tags: word

[image]

Text Version

Put me in a STATE and I will ride a car

Put me in a CAR and I will talk on a phone

Put me in a PHONE and I will stay put

Can you tell me what word I am? __________

Hint 1

> Think of company names

Hint 2

> It is a 2 letter word.

Comment: Is STATE one of the 50 states of the USA or it's the word that comes before "of shock" for example?

Comment: One of the 50 states abbreviated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you the word:

> No

Put me in a STATE and I will ride a car

> Add 'No' to the state of Virginia (VA) and get Nova. A few manufacturers have produced a Nova model, including Chevrolet, Holden, and my personal favourite, [Anziel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anziel_Nova).

Put me in a CAR and I will talk on a phone

> Add 'No', this time to the Korean car manufacturer Kia, and get 'Nokia', a well known phone and blunt weapon.

Put me in a PHONE and I will stay put

> Add 'No' to '[T-Mobile](https://www.t-mobile.com/)' and you get 'Not-Mobile'. That describes something that will be staying put for a while.

Edit for the title:

Your answer may not make any sense to me

> The exact question being asked is: "Can you tell me what word I am?". The answer is "Yes: No." Which does sound somewhat nonsensical

Comment: That last one is very funny :)

Comment: There! You have it @Johnson. Perfectly solved.